# C# program behaving differently after deployment

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have solution that I have created in Visual studio 2010.   It
has two projects, let's say that these projects are `project A`
and `project B`.  A user inputs parameters into `project A` and then `project B`
is suppose to generate random numbers in random colums in an excel file.  The output is supposed to be saved in an Excel file randomly.

When I test the program using Visual Studio 2010 it behaves as desired. Now when I package the
program and create a setup `.exe` file it doesn't randomise.  Instead, the output is saved sequentially.

Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem?

Here is the sample code for generatin random postions

```
 public void AppendCards(int seriesNumber, int batchSize, string cardVal, long batchId)
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        Random ran = new Random();
        int commentsNumber = comments.Count - 1;
        List<int> position = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < seriesNumber + 1; i++)
        {
            position.Add(i);
        }



        long CardTypeId = DataAcc.GetCardTypeId(cardVal);
        WinningCard sc = new WinningCard();
        sc.BatchId = batchId;
        sc.CardTypeId = CardTypeId;
        sc.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

        int winpos = random.Next(1, seriesNumber);
        switch (winpos)
        {
            case 1:
                sc.PositionOne = cardVal;
                break;
            case 2:
                sc.PositionTwo = cardVal;
                break;
            case 3:
                sc.PositionThree = cardVal;

                break;
            case 4:
                sc.PositionFour = cardVal;
                break;
            case 5:
                sc.PositionFive = cardVal;
                break;
        }

        for (int k = 1; k <= seriesNumber; k++)
        {
            int w = random.Next(0, DataAcc.GetCommets().Count);
            switch (k)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (sc.PositionOne == "")
                    {
                        sc.PositionOne = comments[w].CommentDescription;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (sc.PositionTwo == "")
                    {
                        sc.PositionTwo = comments[w].CommentDescription;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (sc.PositionThree == "")
                    {
                        sc.PositionThree = comments[w].CommentDescription;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (sc.PositionFour == "")
                    {
                        sc.PositionFour = comments[w].CommentDescription;
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (sc.PositionFive == "")
                    {
                        sc.PositionFive = comments[w].CommentDescription;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please include some code to show us what you are trying.

Comment: tell us about **saved sequentially** ...

Comment: Yip, this isn't helping a whole lot. 

Can I suggest if it's too much to post all the code (you can always post a link to pastebin), to try recreate the problem using a simple Hello World type program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess - you are calling `AppendCards` rapidly several times in a row and are getting the same numbers? This is because you are creating a new `Random` instance inside this method - move that out and reuse the same `Random` instance (e.g. by making `random` an instance variable).

`Random` is using the current time as a seed value to determine the sequence of random numbers to generate - if you call `AppendCards` quickly (as in when the app is deployed) the time is the same still and the same number is generated. When you debug this in Visual Studio the problem goes away because when you step through time passes.